# NGINX: Given custom subdomain, location regex matching with $http_user_agent conditional doesn't work

Tags: configuration, nginx

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name ~^(?<custom>.+)\.(test)?website\.com$;

    location ~ ^/event/(\d+)$ {
        proxy_pass_header Server;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Scheme $scheme;
        proxy_intercept_errors on;

        # This is the problematic block
        # This conditional breaks the whole location block.
        # If I commented the if statement, the default proxy_pass works.
        if ($http_user_agent ~* iphone|android) {
            # the proxy_pass indeed works, tested on development machine
            proxy_pass http://frontends/userland/mobile/event/$1;
            break;
        }

        # When above if conditional is enabled, this fails.
        proxy_pass http://frontends/userland/event/$1;
    }
}
```

Noticed that the subdomain matcher inside server_name is pretty much a wildcard.

Why the if conditional doesn't work? If what I'm doing is wrong, what would be the best way to rewrite it?

Nginx version: 1.2.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You overwrite your PCRE captures from `^/event/(\d+)$` by evaluating of `iphone|android` in the `if` condition. So, after rewrite rules performed the `$1` variable is empty.

Try something like this:

```
    set $num $1;
    if ($http_user_agent ~* iphone|android) {
        proxy_pass http://frontends/userland/mobile/event/$num;
    }

    proxy_pass http://frontends/userland/event/$num;
```

Comment: That is precisely what the problem is, the user_agent matching squanders the location capturing. Thank you.

Comment: Instead of `set` directive you can also use named capturing: `location ~ ^/event/(?<num>\d+)$`

Answer (score 0):

See [this](http://wiki.nginx.org/IfIsEvil) and [this, in particular,](http://agentzh.blogspot.com/2011/03/how-nginx-location-if-works.html) on why "if" can be evil in Nginx.

The way things are inherited can often not follow expected forms and directives such as "return" and "rewrite" (with "last") are the only really reliable ones to use within Nginx "if" blocks.

I'll try something such as this instead:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name ~^(?<custom>.+)\.(test)?website\.com$;

    location ~ ^/event/(\d+)$ {
        proxy_pass_header Server;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Scheme $scheme;
        proxy_intercept_errors on;

        if ($http_user_agent ~* iphone|android) {
            return 302 http://frontends/userland/mobile/event/$1;
            # Alternative syntax which should keep original url in browser
            #rewrite ^ http://frontends/userland/mobile/event/$1 last;
        }

        proxy_pass http://frontends/userland/event/$1;
    }
}
```